# Recreate session of root dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using microsoft bot framework for building a messenger bot.

I added menu and i want to handle menu this way :

```
if (activity.Text == "item1_postback" || activity.Text == "item2_postback")
{
  await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MenuDialog());

}
else
{
  await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootLuisDialog());
}
```

item1_postback and item2_postback are buttons from menu.

Inside MenuDialog i have functions. 
When everything has finished inside MenuDialog i want to "restore" root dialog and recreate root dialog from RootLuisDialog.

I tried with context.Done and context.Reset, but it does not work.

Any idea how to reset root dialog when MenuDialog has finished ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your message endpoint leave just calling your root dialog

`await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootLuisDialog());`

In your RootLuisDialog, add `[RegexPattern("^item1_postback")]` action detectors for processing post backs.

In these actions, start a menu child dialog by calling

`context.Call(new MenuDialog(), (context, result) => { /*Do something. at this point your are back to the parent dialog.*/});`

After your MenuDialog has finished (it means somewhere you should call `done(some_result)` you'll be back in you parent dialog that is RootLuisDialog and continue processing new user commands.